# Concurrency Batch filling the database

Tags: java, database, multithreading, concurrency, batch-processing

I have an `embedded SQL DataBase` that contains 2 million+ rows with String and Integer fields.
 The dataBase is filled by addBatch and executeBatch operations where one batch = 100.000 requests.

**The function which create one Batch:**

```java
limit = 100000
public void insertData(data) {
   if (insertCounter >= limit) {
     flushToDb();
   }
   prepareInsert.setString(1, data.getString());
   prepareInsert.setString(2, data.getString());
   prepareInsert.setString(3, data.getString());
   prepareInsert.setString(4, data.getString());
   prepareInsert.setInteger(5, data.getInteger());
   prepareInsert.setString(6, data.getString());
   prepareInsertRef.setInteger(7, data.getInteger());
   prepareInsertRef.addBatch();
   insertCounter++;
}
```

When I use only one thread the database is filled in 13 seconds.
However, when I try to add the concurrency my performance does not increase.
In my case I create

```java
executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(THREAD_NUMBER);
```

It executes the *InsertDate* tasks from the [BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) concurrently, but my program's running time increases to 18 seconds.
In the project I use the `HSQL database` because it supports concurrency write and read operations.

I'd like to hear your ideas on how to improve my multi-threads solution for database filling.

Comment: Maybe a single connection can't handle concurrent writes, have you tried with multiple connections or connection pools?